# Laravel : All validation rules fail always

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate a retrieved form with User::$rules and the validation always return failed with all the fields required ! and when i died and dump the `Input::All()` in the controller i get all the input fields i gave when submitted the form which means the issue is in the Model, right ? I never had such a weird problem ! Help please

### Controller :  UsersController

```cpp
public function postSinscrire() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);


    if($validator->passes())  {
        $user = new User;
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->email_confirmation = Input::get('email_confirmation');
        $user->number = Input::get('number');
        $user->pseudo = Input::get('pseudo');
        $user->banned_user = 0;
        $user->activation_email = 0;
        $user->activation_number = 0;
        $user->sex = Input::get('sex');
        $user->birth = Input::get('birth');
        $user->wilaya_code = Input::get('wilaya_code');
        $user->user_type = 1;
        $user->password = hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->password_confirmation('password_confirmation');
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('membre')
            ->with('message', 'Welcome');
    }
    if($validator->failed()) {
            return Redirect::to('membre/sinscrire')
                ->with('message','Une erreur s\'est produise, Corrigez puis réessayez a nouveau')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
            }
```

### Model : User

```cpp
 protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    protected $fillable = array(

        'email','number','pseudo','sex','birth','wilaya_code',

        );

    public static $rules = array(

        'email'=>'max:254|unique:users|email|required',
        'email_confirmation'=>'max:254|unique:users|email|required',
        'number'=>'between:8,15|unique:users',
        'pseudo'=>'max:35|unique:users|required|alpha_num',
        'banned_user'=>'boolean|integer',
        'activation_email'=>'boolean|integer',
        'activation_number'=>'boolean|integer',
        'sex'=>'boolean|integer|required',
        'birth'=>'required|date',
        'wilaya_code'=>'integer|required|max:2',
        'activation_date'=>'date',
        'user_type'=>'integer',
        'password'=>'required|between:8,12|alpha_num|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required|between:8,12|alpha_num'

        );
```

And then i get the required error for all fields !

- The email field is required.
- The email confirmation field is required.
- The pseudo field is required.
- The sex field is required.
- The birth field is required.
- The wilaya code field is required.
- The password field is required.
- The password confirmation field is required.

### Updated : View

```cpp
{{ Form::open(array(
    'url'=>'membre/sinscrire',
    'method'=>'POST'
    )) }}

<label for="email">Email :</label>
{{ Form::text('email')}} <br>

<label for="email_confirmation">Email :</label>
{{ Form::text('email_confirmation')}} <br>

<label for="pseudo">Identifiant ( pseudo ) :</label>
{{ Form::text('pseudo')}} <br> 

<label for="password">Mot de passe :</label>
{{ Form::password('password')}} <br>

<label for="password_confirmation">Confirmation :</label>
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation')}} <br>

<label for="gender">Sexe :</label>
{{ Form::select('gender',array('0'=>'Homme', '1'=>'Femme'))}} <br>

<label for="sana_hilwa">Date de naissance :</label>
{{ Form::selectRange('year', 1930, 2011); }}
{{ Form::selectRange('month', 01, 12); }}
{{ Form::selectRange('day', 01, 31); }} <br>

<label for="al_wilaya">Wilaya :</label>
{{ Form::select('al_wilaya', array(
            '1' => 'Adrar',
            '2' => 'Chlef',
            '31' => 'Oran'
    )) }} <br>

En cliquant sur “Je m'inscris”, vous indiquez que vous avez lu, compris et accepté les <a href="/apropos"><strong>conditions d\'utilisation</strong></a> de Ouedkniss. <br>

{{ Form::submit('Inscrivez vous')}}

{{ Form::close()}}
```

and when i `dd('Input::all');`

```cpp
array (size=11)
  '_token' => string 'mCVboVC123456789nDpOJZXyjiY5YsUrjRMGunPx' (length=40)
  'email' => string 'foo@bar.com' (length=11)
  'email_confirmation' => string 'foo@bar.com' (length=11)
  'pseudo' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  'password' => string 'testpass' (length=8)
  'password_confirmation' => string 'testpass' (length=8)
  'gender' => string '0' (length=1)
  'year' => string '1930' (length=4)
  'month' => string '1' (length=1)
  'day' => string '1' (length=1)
  'al_wilaya' => string '1' (length=1)
```

## Note: the birth field is not done correctly from the view

i was hoping get only the birth field required, if this is the problem, any view script that is compatible with Carbon ?
Thank you

## update : DD('User::$rules');

```cpp
array (size=14)
  'email' => string 'required|max:254|email|unique:users|confirmed' (length=45)
  'email_confirmation' => string 'required|max:254|email|unique:users' (length=35)
  'number' => string 'between:8,15|unique:users' (length=25)
  'pseudo' => string 'required|alpha_num|max:35|unique:users' (length=38)
  'banned_user' => string 'boolean|integer' (length=15)
  'activation_email' => string 'boolean|integer' (length=15)
  'activation_number' => string 'boolean|integer' (length=15)
  'sex' => string 'required|boolean|integer' (length=24)
  'birth' => string 'required|date' (length=13)
  'wilaya_code' => string 'required|max:2|integer' (length=22)
  'activation_date' => string 'date' (length=4)
  'user_type' => string 'integer' (length=7)
  'password' => string 'required|between:8,12|alpha_num|confirmed' (length=41)
  'password_confirmation' => string 'required|between:8,12|alpha_num' (length=31)
```

Comment: what you get on `dd(Input::all());` ?

Comment: `Input::get('email ')` contains a blank space, **I think** you did the same in your html form but not in your `rules`.

Comment: @Razor there is no blank spaces in the code,i did the mistake here sorry

Comment: @Deena i posted my Blade Form check after the update

Comment: You are probably getting empty rules, because of the model. Try do dump the User::$rules.

Comment: In Laravel validation rules run in order as they were specified. I'm not sure about the actual implementation, but from your given validation errors, it seems Laravel requires "required" rule to be at the very first in the rules string before any other rules. Update your rules with "required|...." and see whether it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your validation rules carefully.

```
 'email'=>'max:254|unique:users|email|required',
 'email_confirmation'=>'max:254|unique:users|email|required'
 'number'=>'between:8,15|unique:users',
```

If you are updating and used previous email or number, validation will always fail.

If that the case, before you update, fetch your email and number first and check them against input data. If they are match with existing data, don't use validation rules for those fields, else use these validation rules.

Comment: i mentioned the ""unique" rule, and even if i gave an existing data i wait for a unique exception not a required, the form return required for all fields no matter what !, okay i will check the uniqueness of inputs before check the User::$rules

Comment: For the "unique" rule to pass when updating, use it with the user id, i.e.

'max:254|unique:users,'.$this->user()->id

I use Auth so the user is in the request already, you may have another way of getting the user. If the email is part of a different object then use the ID of the object you are saving it against.